# Apache Hama on Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: apache, cluster-computing, amazon-emr, hama

I am trying to run Apache Hama on Amazon Elastic MapReduce using https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/hama script. However, when trying out with one master node and two slave nodes, `peer.getNumPeers()` in the BSP code reports only 1 peer. I am suspecting whether Hama runs in `local` mode.

Moreover, looking at configurations at https://hama.apache.org/getting_started_with_hama.html, my understanding is that the list of all the servers should go in `hama-site.xml` file for property `hama.zookeeper.quorum` and also in `groomservers` file. However, I wonder whether these are being configured properly in the [install script](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/hama/install-hama.sh). Would really appreciate if anyone could point out whether it's a limitation in the script or whether I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Madhura

Hama doesn't always need `groomserver` file to run fully distributed mode. 
`groomserver` file is needed to run hama cluster using only `start-bspd.sh`. But emr-bootstrap-action of hama runs groomservers on each slave nodes using `hama-daemon.sh` file. Code executed in [install script](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/hama/README.md) is as follow.

`$ /bin/hama-daemon.sh --config ${HAMA_HOME}/conf start groom`

I think you need to check the emr logs whether they have error or not.